# Creating a list/dictionary with imported CSV file (pandas) so I can refer to the variables using a web scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, screen-scraping

I would like to import a CSV file which has various Twitter handles into Python using Pandas, and then each of those "usernames" (twitter handles) would be assigned a variable that I can call on in a different code (web scraper) to retrieve the followers.

I am actively trying to learn as much as I can so I wouldn't like the ENTIRE code on all of this, just how I would be able to create workable variables with the CSV file. That way I can get past this step and begin the rest of my learning, but i'm just VERY stuck here.

(Thank you very much in advance, I am having an awesome time learning about Python and was hesitant to ask because I feel like I may be getting out of my realm of knowledge here and getting ahead of myself but I have gone down a rabbit hole it seems)

This is the code I have so far - to call the CSV File

```
 # import the module 
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import pandas



df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\Python Learning\contentinfo.csv')
print(df)
```

and then the output I receive from that is this

```
     Username
0      Obey_Memorii
1         Kingstaxy
2        ParamoreNA
3             Navin
4          ObeyCayd
5              edns
6   LeonBackwardsTV
7         SHORTYPlE
8        Papa_Richh
9       cleggnation
10           xMethy
11          Ahspect
12       KarizMaInc
13       DuncanMors
14        ObeyGrave
15    JustifiedJack
16      mattythebae
17       CyborgLive
18      Legendof_Ti
19     ConnorSparky
20     Nuka Dilucca
21            Toari
22            Paavs
23         Elevated
24         BFRocket
25      END OF LIST
```

[As you can see here I have the file importing, and producing the values that I put in my CSV file, I'm just not sure how i can refer to each one separately later on in my coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFEBf.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] as text, not as a picture or link. Please include the code you've tried so far, sample input and output, and a description of what went wrong with your attempt(s)

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over the list of users using a `for` loop and perform some function in the loop on the username like the `process_user()` function below:

```py
import pandas as pd

# tweepy processing function
def process_user(username):
    print(f'processing: {username}')
    # your logic here

users = pd.read_csv('./twitter_users.csv')

# loop through the users and do stuff
for user in users['Username']:
    process_user(user)
```

You don't *need* to use pandas for this either (I wouldn't if it is just for opening the file):

```py
import csv

def read_csv(path, fieldnames=None, delimiter=','):
    '''return a list of dictionaries
    '''
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames, delimiter=delimiter)
        return [dict(row) for row in reader]

# tweepy processing function
def process_user(username):
    print(f'processing: {username}')
    # your logic here

users = read_csv('./twitter_users.csv')  # or your file path

# loop through the users and do stuff
for user in users:
    process_user(user['Username'])
```

Output:

```
processing: Obey_Memorii
processing: Kingstaxy
processing: ParamoreNA
processing: Navin
processing: ObeyCayd
processing: edns
processing: LeonBackwardsTV
processing: SHORTYPlE
processing: Papa_Richh
processing: cleggnation
processing: xMethy
processing: Ahspect
processing: KarizMaInc
processing: DuncanMors
processing: ObeyGrave
processing: JustifiedJack
processing: mattythebae
processing: CyborgLive
processing: Legendof_Ti
processing: ConnorSparky
processing: Nuka Dilucca
processing: Toari
processing: Paavs
processing: Elevated
processing: BFRocket
processing: END OF LIST
```

Comment: Oh man - what is so cool is that after working through about 12 hours of tutorials and classes, and then I am now on page 100 of the "Automate the Boring Stuff" book - I can actually answer my own question xD - I love looking back only to last week and realizing that all PRINT does is a side effect to the console lol.